# Calculate percentage change for an item in a dataframe that contains multiple items

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataset with symbol, date and oi. I populate the oi every day for the symbol.
I would like to calculate the percentage change in oi from the previous day for all the symbols.

```
                   DATE         OI
SYMBOL                            
HINDALCO    21-FEB-2022   67815300
FSL         21-FEB-2022   29320200
FEDERALBNK  22-FEB-2022  151660000
HINDALCO    22-FEB-2022     114510
FSL         22-FEB-2022   76852100
```

Output

```
SYMBOL    DATE       OI.    #changeOI
HINDALCO 22-FEB-2022 114510  value
FSL      22-FEB-2022 76852100 value
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out using pivot table

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index='SYMBOL',
                    columns='DATE',
                    values='OI',
                    aggfunc='sum')
        .pct_change(axis=1))
```